# can i use graphql in react without using Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

i am trying to use the GraphQl with react.
suggestions gives that to use apollo client for react to implement the graphql to the application.
but i don't want to use it in the first place.

can i use graphql to react without using apollo client?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. We can use GraphQL with React without using Apollo Client. We can use **fetch** or **axios** and can make things work the same.

Below example demonstrates the **usage of fetch to query a GraphQL endpoint.**

```
fetch(<graphql_endpoint>, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ query: '{ posts { title } }' }),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

Same thing can be easily achieved using **axios**. Hope this helps!

Comment: What package we need for that kind of support as in example?Thanks.

Comment: `fetch` is inbuilt in JavaScript. You can directly use it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, because [GraphQL is a spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/) rather than just one company's implementation (no matter how good many consider that implementation to be). At its core, GraphQL is just a query format and structured response. Even a network call is not strictly needed.

You could skip Apollo in the browser too, and just invoke a plain web request. You can easily make an AJAX call with XMLHttpRequest or Fetch API to perform the GraphQL query. The easiest way I can think of to work this out is to install [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) or [Playground](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-playground) somewhere, open up your browser's developer tools, and execute a query. The Network tab of most browser's developer tools will show you all of the request headers and URL parameters you would need.

The Apollo client just does a lot of that work for you and has a very healthy ecosystem to add caching, federation, etc., but there is nothing stopping you from skipping that library and making the HTTP calls yourself with no middlemen.

Comment: GraphQL is transport-agnostic. It is not specific to HTTP. A GraphQL service could execute documents without a network call at all.